# How to use NSNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

In my application there is two viewControllers as `FirstViewController` and `DetailViewController`. 
When tap on a table cell, it navigate to `DetailViewController`. In `DetailViewController`, I want to edit and reload the `FirstViewController`'s table view

How can I use `NSNotification` for this problem?

Here's the method I want to implement `NSNotification` stuff

```
-(IBAction) save{
strSelectedText=theTextField.text;

[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];  

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (objFirstViewController) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];



[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: This isn't a task for a notification. Just have a look at the TableViewProgrammingGuide. You can start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html HTH

Comment: It may be useful to you http://mac-objective-c.blogspot.com/2009/02/nsnotifications-broadcasting-mechanism.html

Comment: I would suggest , you better use delegate pattern rather than notification .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
NSNotification* notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"MyNotification" object:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];  

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector (objFirstViewController) name:@"MyNotification" object:nil];

}


-(IBAction) save{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:MyNotification object:sender];

//this will go to where you implement your selector objFirstViewController.

}

-(void)objFirstViewController:(NSNotification *)notification {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

post the notification from detailViewController and add firstViewController as the observer.

Make sure you remove fireViewController from the observer list from viewDidUnload.

Right now you are adding detailViewController as observer.