# Refresh data on entering foreground in all tab bar

Tags: ios, web-services, tabbar, foreground

I have a small question. I want to refresh (i.e calling web service) my iOS app each time I launch the application and each time the application enters the foreground. And the problem is my app is a `tab bar application`. And the refresh has to occur in all the tabs.

Comment: Try `NSNotification`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161307/how-to-use-nsnotification

Comment: Will it refresh all the tabs too?

Comment: You can `addObserver:` in all tabs and on posting notification selector in all observer invokes. Then put the refresh logic in that selector

Answer (score 0):

First, all ViewControllers should be loaded

After, when applicationDidFinishLaunching or applicationWillEnterForeground

```
for (UIViewController *viewController in rootTabBarController.viewControllers) {
// rootTabBarController = your tab bar
// get all VCs you need.
}
```

Hope this idea helps you