# Pausing iPhone Game for Interruptions in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to make it so that my game pauses when a battery warning pops up, or there is an incoming call. I know the method "applicationWillResignActive:" is called for one of these interruptions but here is my problem. My current Pause method is in my custom Game class and I'm not sure how to call it from the app delegate or if there is something else I should do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the Notification Center to send a message to another part of your code. When you receive the `applicationWillResignActive:` call, you post a message to Notification center:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pauseGame" object:self];
```

Then, you set your game code to listen for these notifications (when the game is initialized):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(receivePauseNotification:)
                                             name:@"pauseGame"
                                           object:nil];
```

Your method that will be called from this just needs to pause the game, however it is supposed to do that according to your own code:

```
- (void) receivePauseNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if (![[notification name] isEqualToString:@"pauseGame"])
    {
        NSLog (@"Error; unknown notification received");
        return;
    }

    // pause the game here.
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 8 seconds. Kudos to you for including code samples. :-)

Comment: @WorkingDev I was typing fast! (And, I was surprised to see your answer so quickly afterwards.)

Comment: Instead of using `@pauseGame` everywhere, define, at least, a `#define` in a single header file or, better, an `extern NSString *kMyPauseGameNotificationName;` global...

Answer (score 1):

Set up a notification using `NSNotificationCenter`. When `applicationWillResignActive:` is called fire off a notification. Your custom game class should then be set up as an observer of the notification and pause the game when the notification comes in. Here's info on using `NSNotificationCenter`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Here is a stack overflow question that also shows how to use it:
[How to use NSNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161307/how-to-use-nsnotification)

There are also many many tutorials on-line that explain how to use it.